# Can I store some variable into the hover function?

Tags: jquery, hover

Seems that I can't store the `linguettaCorrente` variable into the hover handler :

```
$('.navigatore_blocco').hover(
    var linguettaCorrente=$(this).find('linguetta');

    function() {
        linguettaCorrente.animate( { height: 33 }, 600);
    },

    function() {
        linguettaCorrente.animate( { height: 23 }, 600);
    }
);
```

why? And how can I store it?

Comment: THe why is quite simple: hover is a function and you're just adding a random parameter where you shouldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the same var outside the hover and define it inside.

```
var linguettaCorrente = null;
$('.navigatore_blocco').hover(
    function() {
        linguettaCorrente = $(this).find('linguetta');
        linguettaCorrente.animate( { height: 33 }, 600);
    },
    function() {
        linguettaCorrente.animate( { height: 23 }, 600);
    }
);
```

`.hover` function takes 2 argument and those 2 are functions. It cannot be anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use `.data()` to store the needed data?

```
$('.navigatore_blocco').hover(
    var linguettaCorrente=$(this).find('linguetta');
    $(this).data('linguetaaCorrente', linguettaCorrente);
    ....
);
```